# What classes do I use to make an iPhone act as a server?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, httpserver

I'm looking for an easy way for users to download content from an iPhone to their computer.  I've seen other apps that actually turn the iPhone into a server and give the user an IP address to navigate to on their computer.  I've glanced at some Apple samples, but nothing looked too much like what I was going for.

So what's the easiest way to make a server that listens on TCP port 80 (even better, an HTTP server) and sends responses?  Hopefully using Objective C classes, but I can make a wrapper if there isn't anything available.

Comment: This is an excellent question.  I look forward to hearing an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Google Toolbox for Mac](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/) has a class called **GTMHTTPServer**.

Deusty Designs has a project called [CocoaHTTPServer](http://code.google.com/p/cocoahttpserver/).

You can't use port 80 because it requires root access.

Comment: Deusty Design's project:  Incredibly helpful, and simple to use!

Comment: By the way, IPv6 is not available on iPhone OS. But you may find that it works in the Simulator. So, beware.

Answer (score 2):

Cocoa provides lots of support for client-side networking but not a lot for server-side.

At the lowest level, you can use normal BSD sockets.

The next level up is CoreFoundation (plain C but using Cocoa-like types). Relevant CoreFoundation APIs are `CFNetwork`, `CFSocket` and `CFStream` (`CFStream` is a file-stream that can have its source through a network -- it is not a System V style network Stream).

In Objective-C, you can look at `NSStream` which is the Objective-C equivalent of `CFStream`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good O'Reilly article on setting up a simple server.

[How to Write a Cocoa Web Server](http://oreilly.com/pub/a/mac/2006/11/14/how-to-write-a-cocoa-web-server.html)

He uses NSFileHandle and NSSocketPort to setup a listener and handle requests. He also gets into some of the detail work of using the BSD sockets directly. I have had luck with this approach in the past.

This was written back in 2006, and I haven't used this on an iPhone project yet, but the classes he uses are pretty common. I would give it a fighting chance of working for an iPhone project.